# How do I limit the number of tabs in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Is it possible to limit the number of tabs that can be opened in IE8?  Is that something that can be handled by a rule enforced through a registry key, or something like that, in Windows 7 Ultimate?

Comment: Do you mean tabs?

Comment: Yes, I mean the tabs in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/askie/archive/2009/03/09/opening-a-new-tab-may-launch-a-new-process-with-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx) article describes the new model within IE8 for handling tabs in detail.

Basically it's limited to how many copies of explorer it can launch on your machine, so therefore the limit will be the amount of memory it can have access to or in the almost impossible event of you running out of threads.

There is a registry tweak to control how it opens the tabs, but none to restrict them.

Comment: @Diago: "Basically it's limited to how many copies of explorer it can launch on your machine" - Yes, then there is a soft limit to it. On most systems it's 32,768 tabs, minus the number of any other running programs.

Comment: @amp Good point.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no limitation by number of tabs, but there is computer memory limitation for that.